# Multiable Choice Dropdown Menu

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

Let's say you have a dropdown box and a database. My data base consists of airport data as follows:

```
terminal |  origin |  airline |  flight | scheduledDate | scheduledTime | status 
t1         dubai      cityjet    WX113    2016-11-17      11:45           due 11:47
t2         frankfurt  ryanair    FR6874   2016-11-17      11:50           due 12:00
t1  ....
```

So I have my HTML written up and I need to make a dropdown menu using PHP and in that I have to count all flights recorded by terminal, and then by each terminal t1 and t2.
I checked my figures and by using

```
SELECT COUNT(terminal) FROM arrivals;
select count(terminal) from arrivals where terminal='t1';
select count(terminal) from arrivals where terminal='t2';
```

which gives me a total of

```
Total Flights | 7492
Terminal 1    | 4167
Terminal 2    | 3325
```

But I need to take this data and put it into my HTML using PHP and create a dropdown menu displaying total as above and then the dropdown menu allows me to find total flights for each month

```
<!--dropdown menu -->
Arrival Stats for Month: | <ALL> | Find
Total Flights | 7492
Terminal 1    | 4167
Terminal 2    | 3325
```

By using the dropdown menu for December Results I get

```
Arrival Stats for Month: | December | Find
Total Flights | 897
Terminal 1    | 471
Terminal 2    | 426
```

I'm just so confused by the entire thing, do I need to put in individual option values in the form

```
<option value="All">ALL</option>
<option value="id1">JAN</option>
<option value="id2">FEB</option>
<option value="id3">MAR</option>
```

and then using the id's do I create variables and turn them into querys and echo the results into the table?

Sorry for the long post, just been staring at this the last two days and getting no where with it

Comment: Use an alias for each COUNT, assign a variable to it for the said aliases, then echo them in variables in the dropdown.

Comment: People have no interest in helping you because while you describe the question well you don't post any of the code you have written or show any effort at all in solving the problem.  You need to show both your code and explain how it is not doing what you expect.

Comment: @Patrick, from your question, it seems you already have the algorithm(put it in options and then you can use form, Java script, or whatever technique you like to get the result when user choose value in drop down and change it into query and echo the results into the table)... and now try it and change it into working code ...

Comment: @Hogan I didn't ask to write the code, I just need direction, if you look at a previous question I asked you can see that I have have written code before. Im just confused on what I need to do as previously my other dropdown box got the results from a specific row, this dropdown box I have to create the values, just confused on how I link it in with my database query when you select the option

Comment: Thanks Fred and Ivan, will try that =]